# What's the cause of these three error popups? Should I be concerned?

Tags: azure-functions

The popped up in rapid succession in the azure portal while I was working. But I have no errors in my function app.

---

Error:

We are unable to reach your function app (Service Unavailable). Please try again later.

Session Id: 53306646fe66442b8ee4ed3c908a95dd

Timestamp: 2017-03-02T05:50:28.432Z

---

Error:

Host Error: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Session Id: 53306646fe66442b8ee4ed3c908a95dd

Timestamp: 2017-03-02T05:50:34.508Z

---

Error:

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Session Id: 53306646fe66442b8ee4ed3c908a95dd

Timestamp: 2017-03-02T05:51:19.225Z

Comment: Seems to be broken. Now I see this red popup:

Error:
 
We are unable to reach your function app. Your app could be having a temporary issue or may be failing to start. You can check logs or try again in a couple of minutes. 
 
Session Id: 042f94b68988472287693072abe6d802
 
Timestamp: 2017-03-02T06:43:50.650Z

Comment: I was also getting some intermittent errors like that today. Also, the UI got updated, so might be related.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have authentication enabled for your functions? If you do, you will get several types of pop ups indicating that there's an error. It doesn't affect their ability to run or anything, but it does cause spurious pop up errors in the dashboard and seems to prevent the "Monitor" page from working. If you do have it enabled, try turning it off just to see if the pop ups go away (as a test, not a long term solution).